# Oracle SQL connections in Groovy and its classes

Tags: sql, oracle, groovy

I'm new to Groovy and I have a simple class with a "public static void main" that executes SQL via sql.execute and sql.call statements using groovy.sql.sql as an import.  I'm also importing a Service that checks security settings within an existing application in the Oracle database.  It also executes SQL statements.  My question is, how do people usually accomplish the SQL connections?  Do you open a connection per class, ie a separate SQL connection within each class?  Or can you pass your SQL connection info to that class and use the same connection somehow?  Right now I have it working with two separate connections though I'm not sure if that's a good way to accomplish this or not.

If the above isn't making complete sense (since I'm a newbie), here is a sample of my code.  In my main class I open and call SQL like this:

```
//DB connection
def conn = new DbConnectService()           
def sql = Sql.newInstance(conn.url, conn.username, conn.password, conn.driver)
```

Then I want to check the security settings with a call to the security check class like this:

```
// Security check
def sec = new CheckSecurityService()
sec.SecurityCheck(ProgramName)
```

The Security check, after opening the exact same DB connection as above, does some SQL calls like this:

```
try 
{
        sql.call '{call G$_SECURITY.G$_VERIFY_PASSWORD1_PRD(?, ?, ?, ?)}', [$p_object, p_version, sql.VARCHAR, Sql.VARCHAR], { p_pass, p_rol ->
            p_password = p_pass
            p_role = p_rol
        }
```

Then if it's successful I return to my main class and do more sql statements such as:

```
sql.execute("insert into test (key1, text) values (${foo}, ${text1})")
```

Any information on how people usually do this is appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: Nobody?  Seems like this should be easier than I've made it but I cannot find the answer after much searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you stated you are doing it all in `main` thread, I assume it's a single threaded application. Then it should be okay to reuse connection. Ideally, in multithreaded applications, you should work with DataSource and some underlying connection pool instead of directly opening and closing Connection in your code.

Here you may pass the same `Sql` object or `Connection` to your security checker class without actually creating two connections. And even if you creating two connection, it's not a big deal (unless you are doing that in some loop, or facing some performance issue)

One suggestion : For insert use prepared statement like syntax instead of string interpolation

`sql.execute("insert into test (key1, text) values (${foo}, ${text1})")`

`sql.execute("insert into test (key1, text) values (?, ?)", [foo, text1])`

Comment: Right, definitely single-threaded.  I'm concerned about rollback and such when something errors out.  I've researched the transactional parameter, does that also work with connection pooling so I wouldn't have to worry about it?  Per your suggestion to use prepared statements, is there a reason you suggest it?  Thanks!

Comment: For single thread app (unless very long running process), I don't see need of connection pool. Transactions work at connection level and Pool just returns you a connection from a bunch of pooled connections instead of creating new connection every time, and that doesn't affect transactions. ${var} will make the query vulnerable to sql injection and other syntactical issues, prepared statements save you from that trouble.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for the info.  Is there a way to reuse the connection without passing the sql connection info to every method I call from another service?  Seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: Accept connection in the constructor and pass it while instantiating. Methods of the class can use it as instance variable.

Comment: Thanks kunal!  I had to research some of those terms but I was able to implement it.  :)